# OpenCV - getting pixel data from camera device

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using OpenCV 2.4.6. I have found over the Internet some example of getting frame from a camera. It works well (it displays my ugly face onto the screen). However, I absolutely cannot get pixel data from the frames. I've found some topic here: http://answers.opencv.org/question/1934/reading-pixel-values-from-a-frame-of-a-video/ but it doesn't work for me.

Here is the code - in the commented parts I pointed out what is wrong.

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main() {
    int c;
    IplImage* img;
    CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(1);
    cvNamedWindow("mainWin", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    while(1) {
        img = cvQueryFrame(capture);

        uchar* data = (uchar*)img->imageData; // access violation

        // this does not work either
        //Mat m(img);
        //uchar a = m.data[0]; // access violation

        cvShowImage("mainWin", img);
        c = cvWaitKey(10);
        if(c == 27)
            break;
    }
}
```

Could you give me some suggestions, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using the newer `Mat` structure instead of `IplImage` since your question is tagged with C++ tag. For your task you can use a `data` member of `Mat` - it points to internal `Mat` storage. For example `Mat img;  uchar* data = img.data;`. Here's a full example

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main() {
    int c;
    Mat img;
    VideoCapture capture(0);
    namedWindow("mainWin", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    bool readOk = true;

    while(capture.isOpened()) {

        readOk = capture.read(img);

        // make sure we grabbed the frame successfully 
        if (!readOk) {
            std::cout << "No frame" << std::endl;
            break;
        }

        uchar* data = img.data; // this should work

        imshow("mainWin", img);
        c = waitKey(10);
        if(c == 27)
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: It throws (even if I remove uchar* data... part) Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x002BF794 and opens the throw.cpp file (pointing the last line in file) in Visual Studio 2012.  :(

Comment: hmm.. this runs fine on my system, no exceptions are thrown. Are you using `cv::Mat` instead of `IplImage` as in the example?

Comment: Yes, I do. From what I see, when I remove imshow() it doesn't throw any exceptions, but obviously I don't see any image.

Comment: make sure that your `img` is not empty. It could be that video capture was not opened or image wasn't read from the camera.

Comment: Hey! That actually worked when I put "if (!img.empty())" before imshow. Thank you!

Comment: cool, I just edited the example with a check that tests if we were able to read the frame successfully.

Comment: btw your two first sentences sound weird: "never use Mat, but use data member of Mat" :)